# How to calculate the mean of a list inside another list Python

Tags: python, list

I want to calculate the mean for each trial and for each subject. I end up with a list of trials embedded in a list of subjects. How can I calculate the mean for each trial per subject?

I have the following code to built the list (27-50 trials) in the list (28 subjects):

```
fsubj_mean_acw =[]

for fil in os.listdir(path):
    #extract SUBJECT name
    r = (fil.split(" ")[0])
    
    dataa = pd.read_csv(path+f'{r} taski_pproc_O12_M.txt',sep=",",usecols=['Time','AFp1','AFp2','F9','AFF5h','AFF1h','AFF2h','AFF6h','F10','FFT9h','FFT7h','FFC5h','FFC3h','FFC1h','FFC2h','FFC4h','FFC6h','FFT8h','FFT10h','FC1','FCz','FC2','FTT9h','FTT7h','FCC5h','FCC3h','FCC1h','FCC2h','FCC4h','FCC6h','FTT8h','FTT10h','Cz','TTP7h','CCP5h','CCP3h','CCP1h','CCP2h','CCP4h','CCP6h','TTP8h','CPz','TPP9h','TPP7h','CPP5h','CPP3h','CPP1h','CPP2h','CPP4h','CPP6h','TPP8h','TPP10h','Pz','PPO1h','PPO2h','P9','PPO9h','POO1','POO2','PPO10h','P10','POO9h','OI1h','OI2h','POO10h'])
      
    # Get names of indexes for which column Time has value -1 (before stim onset)
    indexNames = dataa[dataa['Time'] < -1 ].index
    
    # Delete these row indexes from dataFrame
    dataa=dataa.drop(indexNames , inplace=False)
    # delete first column 'Time'
    dataa = dataa.drop('Time', axis = 1)
    # cut big file of 27 to  50 trials in segments of 1 trial
    group_size = 7500
    #cut the data in parts for every trial
    datao = [dataa.iloc[i:i+group_size] for i in range(0,len(dataa),group_size)]
    if len(dataa) < group_size:
       dataa.pop()

    m_acw = []
  
    for data in datao:
        acw = []
        for columns in data[0:len(data):1]:
            ACWr = calc_a_acw(data[columns], n_lag=(500))           
            ACWW = (ACWr*2)/500            
            acw.append(ACWW)                         
            mn_acw = np.asarray(acw)
            
        m_acw.append(mn_acw)        
    fsubj_mean_acw.append(m_acw)
    
fnp_subj_mean_acw_500  =np.asarray(fsubj_mean_acw)#this line does not get executed properly but I'm not sure if I really need this.
```

Just for information, this code runs but I get the following message:

```
C:\Users\LPC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py:83: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
```

Here a plot of how my data looks like: I want the mean for the pink column.
[image]

I hope I'm clear but new to python, so please don't hesitate for specifications if I missed some elements.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Would the numpy.mean function do what you need? [documentation link](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate means of nested lists, then you can calculate it with numpy.

```py
trials = [
   [1, 2, 3],
   [2, 3, 4]
]
means = np.mean(trials, axis=1)
subjects = [...] # size len(trials)
grades = dict(zip(subjects, means)) # Dictionary with subject as key and mean as value
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your comments.
When I adapt your code to my data:
````means = np.mean(fsubj_mean_acw, axis=1)
subjects = [...] # size len(trials)
grades = dict(zip(subjects, means)) # Dictionary with subject as key and mean as value````
I get following error:  ````AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1````

Comment: That means you passing into `mean` function 1 dimensional array, when you should pass 2d array, like list of lists, not list of numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
t = [
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4]
    ]

s = ['A','B']

print ({ k:sum(v)/len(v) for k,v in zip(s,t) })
```

Output:

```
{'A': 2.0, 'B': 3.0}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I finally made it work with the following code: ````meann=[]
n =[]
numm=[]
for lst in subj_mean_acw:
    m =[]
    n = len(lst)
    numm.append(n)
    for col in lst:
        m = np.mean(col)
        meann.append(m)
        ```` Thank you very much!